# Cкрыть результат вывода json

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

Как скрыть вывод `json` в нижеуказанном коде (или обойти это)? Сейчас `echo` выводит содержимое `json` на странице. Без вывода `echo` консоль выводит

> "JSON.parse: unexpected end of data".

```
<?
    $out = json_encode(array(
        surname => $surname_php, //присваиваем переменным в объекте,
        //который передадим на клиент имена - 'surname' в данном случае
        email => $email_php,
        ...//остальные переменные
    ));
    echo $out;
?>
<script>
    ...
    success: function(data){
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        $('#surname').val(data['surname']);//собственно data и будет хранить 
        //переменные в ячейках с именами, присвоенными ранее, в php
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Это все один скрипт? Или генерация страницы - это один скрип (например, index.html), а данные запрашиваются из другого (например, data.php) ?

Comment: Да, генерация - это отдельный скрипт, данные запрашиваются из другого.

Comment: Я немного не понял, $out не всегда содержит данные? Чему равно data при ошибке JSON.parse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*допустим файл, который возвращает `JSON` называется `json.php`, а файл, который запрашивает данные `index.html`*

Проблема вот в чем: если вы убираете `echo $out`, то файл `json.php` ничего не возвращает, переменная `data` становится пустой строкой и `JSON.parse` выдает ошибку, потому что пустая строка это **не валидный JSON**

И решения, которое вы хотите, нет. Вам в любом случае нужно, что бы файл `json.php` возвращал какие-то данные. Если к ним можно обратиться через `ajax`, то можно обратиться и напрямую через `http`.

Как вариант "защиты от дурака", это просто добавить в `ajax` данные, либо специальные заголовки

```
$.ajax({
   url,
   headers: {
      from-ajax: true
   }
});
```

А на сервере проверять, что этот заголовок есть, иначе выводить 404 страницу или вообще ничего не выводить. Но это **"защита от дурака"**, потому что запрос всегда можно подделать

Comment: Может я что-то не понял, но не проще ли проверять if (data)

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько если автор уберет `echo $out` то `data` всегда будет пустой, а он как раз и хочет убрать `echo $out`,  я объяснил, почему этого нельзя сделать

Comment: а передевать свои хедеры это норм практика? не лучше будет передать data?

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько _а передавать свои хедеры это норм практика_ ничего плохого в этом нет, в любом случае можно будет подделать запрос

Comment: Вариантом будет совместить эти два скрипта вместе в одной странице/файле и использовать CSRF для защиты от подделки запроса. Насколько я понимаю сессия у вас устанавливается, следовательно эту защиту можно использовать.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял суть вопроса, то возможны как минимум 2 варианта

Первый вариант. Сохранить значение в глобальную переменную

```
var r;
...
success: function(data){
  r = JSON.parse(data);;
}
```

Второй вариант. Использовать jQuery.data() (https://api.jquery.com/data/)

```
success: function(data){
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    $('#surname').data('loaded_data', data);
}
```

Соответственно потом к данным можно будет обратиться вот так

```
var data = $('#surname').data('loaded_data');
```

Comment: у ТСа не в этом вопрос, а в том, как убрать `echo $out` и при этом, что бы скрипт продолжил работать

Comment: То есть в одном случае нужно выводить json, а в другом нет?